# How to store an image as binary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store an image (System.Web.Ui.Image) in a SQL (I use LINQ), for that I need to convert it into Binary (System.Data.Linq.Binary). How to do this?

Comment: I answered you this yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028275/in-asp-net-c-how-to-store-an-image-in-databasesql  See the code sample.

Comment: The problem is probably not storing the image in the database but obtaining the image data from the `Image` object. What I don't really understand is why someone wants to do that - if you have control over the website and emit `Image`s to a page you usually control the images, too. And storing images linked from 3rd party sites into a database while rendering a page for an user seems weired, too.

Comment: Do you mean System.Drawing.Image instead of system.web.ui.image.

Answer (score 0):

The object does not contain any image data - only the URL of the image to display. So you have to download the image file and from there it should be straight forward to stuff the stream into a byte array and store that in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that WebControls.Image does not store the image data, just a
link to where the real image is.